# What is the problem with this simple boost::spirit::qi parser?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I've got this simple parser intended to parse VB style double quoted strings. Thus, the parser should turn something like

```
"This is a quoted string containing quotes ("" "")"
```

into an output of

```
This is a quoted string containing quotes (" ")
```

Here is the grammar I came up with for this:

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace wide = qi::standard_wide;
class ConfigurationParser : public qi::grammar<std::wstring::iterator, std::wstring()>
{
    qi::rule<std::wstring::iterator, std::wstring()> quotedString;
    qi::rule<std::wstring::iterator> doubleQuote;

public:
    ConfigurationParser() : ConfigurationParser::base_type(quotedString, "vFind Command Line")
    {
        doubleQuote = (wide::char_(L'"') >> wide::char_(L'"'));

        quotedString = L'"' >> +(doubleQuote[qi::_val = L'"'] | (wide::char_ - L'"'))>> L'"';
    }
};
```

However, the attribute I'm getting is a single quote mark ("), rather than the full parsed message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without any semantic actions:

```
class ConfigurationParser 
  : public qi::grammar<std::wstring::iterator, std::wstring()> 
{ 
    qi::rule<std::wstring::iterator, std::wstring()> quotedString; 
    qi::rule<std::wstring::iterator, wchar_t()> doubleQuote; 

public: 
    ConfigurationParser() 
      : ConfigurationParser::base_type(quotedString, "vFind Command Line") 
    { 
        doubleQuote = wide::char_(L'"') >> omit[wide::char_(L'"')]; 
        quotedString = L'"' >> +(doubleQuote | (wide::char_ - L'"')) >> L'"'; 
    } 
};
```

The `omit[]` directive still executes the embedded parser but doesn't expose any attribute, making the doubleQuote rule return a single `L'"'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't save the result properly:

```
doubleQuote[qi::_val = L'"']
```

Here, because of the '=' sign, you override what was already in. Try with '+=' instead.

```
doubleQuote[qi::_val += L'"']
```

Also, I don't know if saving is automatic, you may have to add the same '+=' after the other parser in the alternative:

```
(wide::char_ - L'"')[qi::_val += boost::spirit::arg_names::_1]
```

But I am not that good with Qi so perhaps it IS automated, which would make sense.

Comment: That sort of makes sense except for the fact that `std::wstring` has no member assigning from a `wchar_t` ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not entirely sure why, but I was able to fix it by moving that assignment action into the sub rule:

```
doubleQuote %= (wide::char_(L'"') >> L'"')[qi::_val = L'"'];
doubleQuote.name("double quote");

quotedString = L'"' >> +(doubleQuote | (wide::char_ - L'"')) >> L'"';
quotedString.name("quoted string");
```

Note the use of `operator %=` for doubleQuote and the fact that the semantic action is now located there.